# TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null

Tags: javascript, node.js, microsoft-azure, base64

Eu estou com esse problema e não faço ideia de como resolver, quero salvar imagens no storage da Azure

```
const blobSvc = azure.createBlobService(config.containerConnectionString);

    let filename = guid.raw().toString() + '.jpg';
    let rawdata = req.body.image;
    let matches = rawdata.match(/^data:([A-Za-z-+\/]+);base64,(.+)$/);
    let type = matches[1];
    let buffer = new Buffer(matches[2], 'base64');

await blobSvc.createBlockBlobFromText('images', filename, buffer, {
            contentType: type
        }, function (error, result, response) {
            if (error) {
                filename = 'default-product.png'
            }
        });
```

O erro e apontado aqui

> let type = matches[1];

mas eu não consigo entender para resolver, e a mensagem de erro:

> TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null

não ajuda muito, alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: Esse erro provavelmente é porque o `match` é null. Ou seja, não encontrou nada com a regex usada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Muito provável que seu rawdata.match está null.
Para não ocorrer erro verifique sua variável rawdata antes:

```
if (matches)
{
    let type = matches[1];
    let buffer = new Buffer(matches[2], 'base64');
}
```

Comment: Se o `rawdata` fosse `null` o erro seria: `TypeError: rawdata is null`.
Você teria que testar `matches` e não `rawdata.`

Comment: @fernandosavio, exato.. Escrevi uma coisa e coloquei no if outra.. Ajustado, grato!

Comment: Show! o -1 era meu pra evitar dar informação errada.
Já retirei! :D

Comment: @8biT, valeu funcionou, só tive que trocar let por var